# Is there a way to force excel to reject commas as values for row data?

Tags: excel

I am allowing users to enter in data to an excel sheet. I want the data they enter to be whole plain numbers. If user enters in commas with their number excel would ignore the comma and just have the whole plain number for the row data. Is there a way to do that? I guess a way to change the data type of the row?

Comment: Just change the format to a numeric format that does not show the commas. So long as the entered value is numeric, it will be displayed as you want.  You cannot really change the data type.  It will be what is entered. But you can change how it is displayed. And a number, whether entered with or without commas, will always be stored without the commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not exactly do what you want because it will not allow them to enter the comma in the first place, rather than removing the comma.

1. Select the range of cells
2. On the data tab, select data validation.
3. From the Allow drop-down, choose "Whole Number"
4. In the Data drop down and other options, configure the filter to allow the type of whole number you want (for example, for positive numbers choose "greater than", then 0.
5. On the error alert tab of the popup, fill out the error message to say "Please enter a whole plain number only".
6. Click OK

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click on the row number
2. Cell properties
3. Custom

Answer (score 1):

- Open the VBEditor with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>;
- You will see something like the picture below;
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> if you do not see it;

[image]

- On `ThisWorkbook` paste this code:

---

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.OnKey ","
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnKey ",", "NotAllowed"
End Sub
```

- Then select ThisWorkbook > Right Mouse Button > Add > Modul.
- In a `Module` paste this:

---

```
Public Sub NotAllowed()
    MsgBox ("Not allowed to use the "","" key!")
End Sub
```

Now, whenever someone <kbd>,</kbd> they will see:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This Macro will actively remove commas both in data and formatting from any entered data in a specified range. You will need to right-click on the sheet name and choose "view code" to add the event.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim NO_COMMAS_REGION As Range
    Set NO_COMMAS_REGION = Range("A:A") ' Replace this with whatever the region is where you want to prevent commas


   For Each cell In Target
        If Not (Application.Intersect(cell, NO_COMMAS_REGION) Is Nothing) Then
            If InStr(cell.Value, ",") > 0 Then
                cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, ",", "")
            End If
            cell.NumberFormat = "0"
        End If

    Next cell
End Sub
```